# MySQL: create a sequence by order of appearance

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to spot number of the same values in a column and give a sequence number to them.
For example if I have a table with a column D with the Data:

**D**
A
A
B
A
B
C
C
D

I need to create a column S with the sequential number of the data:

**D  S**
A  1
A  2
B  1
A  3
B  2
C  1
C  2
D  1

As you may see for example there are three A and they get a number according to the order of appearance. The same with the rest of the data.
I am not very experienced with SQL, may someone help on this?

Comment: Do you have any other column to determine the order you gave in example? If no then there is no guarantee that you will get data in same order that you mentioned in example. If yes then give that column details also.

Comment: Rows in SQL have no order

Comment: Then the result can different every time the query is executed

Comment: I initially fill the table from a csv files and the order is important. The actual problem is that I will also have another column (ID_Lang) and for the first A with ID_Lang = 1 I have to give the same S to the first A with ID_Lang = 2

Comment: There is now way to determine the order that rows are inserted into your table after insertion has completed, unless there is something like an auto-increment id in your table.

Comment: I am using LOAD DATA INFILE to load the csv. So the rows will not be necessarily be entered in the table by the same order they are in the csv?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there is an `id` field in your table that determines row order, you can use the following query to get the desired result:

```
SELECT id, D, (SELECT COUNT(*) + 1
               FROM mytable AS t2
               WHERE t1.D = t2.D AND t2.id < t1.id) AS S
FROM mytable AS t1
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/83dd9/1)

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. Now if I use LOAD DATA INFILE and some auto-increment field am I guaranteed to get the rows by the order they are in the csv files?

Comment: If `LOAD DATA INFILE` inserts data into your table in the order they are listed in the excel file, then it is guaranteed that the auto_increment field will reflect this order.